# Individual value labels for side-by-side count barplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I am trying to create a side-by-side barplot of count values with value labels in ggplot 2, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add value labels to the individual side-by-side bars.

I am using the following dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shubhamgupta012/titanic-dataset/data

Here is the code I used:

```
titanic <- read_csv("titanic.csv")

titanicgg <- ggplot(titanic)

titanicgg + geom_bar(aes(x=Pclass, fill=as.factor(Survived)), position=position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
    labs(title="Survival by Passenger Class", x = "Passenger Class", y = "Count") + 
    theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red3", "steelblue3"), name=element_blank(), 
                      labels=c("Did Not Survive", "Survived")) + 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=25, face="bold"), axis.title=element_text(size=15), 
          legend.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
    geom_text(stat = 'count',aes(label = ..count.., vjust = -0.2, x=Pclass), position = position_dodge(.9))
```

I expected to achieve a plot with value labels for the individual side-by-side bars, but instead the value labels appear for the total for each class category, as shown in the picture of the plot below. How can I get the labels to appear for the individual bars (individual labels for first class survived, first class did not survive, etc.)?

[graph generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4bPT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `geom_text` function should include the `Survived` variable in the `aes()` and
The dot-dot notation (`..count..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `after_stat(count)` instead.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(titanic, aes(x = Pclass, fill = as.factor(Survived))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
  labs(title = "Survival by Passenger Class", x = "Passenger Class", y = "Count") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red3", "steelblue3"), 
                    name = element_blank(), 
                    labels = c("Did Not Survive", "Survived")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 13)) +
  # geom_text(stat = 'count', 
  #           aes(label = ..count.., group = Survived, 
  #               vjust = -0.2, x = Pclass), 
  #           position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count), group = Survived, 
                vjust = -0.2, x = Pclass), 
            stat = 'count', 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]